# Save array images from display.loadRemoteImage

Tags: image, load, coronasdk

display.loadRemoteImage( "http://developer.anscamobile.com/demo/hello.png", "GET", networkListener, "helloCopy.png", system.TemporaryDirectory, 50, 50 )

Hello, I want to obtain a ARRAY of images from my server with:

data[i].image = display.loadRemoteImage(URLlimpia, "GET", networkListener, "LOGO" .. i .. ".png" , system.TemporaryDirectory )

But the images always appears on the simulator screen and I want to save in any place to show later on a LIST.

How can I do it??

*** How can I clean the image from the screen when it appears??

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
local function networkListener( event )
        if ( event.isError ) then
                print ( "Network error - download failed" )
        else
                event.target.isVisible = false
        end

        print ( "RESPONSE: " .. event.response )
end

display.loadRemoteImage( "http://www.coronalabs.com/demo/hello.png", "GET", networkListener, "helloCopy.png", system.TemporaryDirectory, 50, 50 )
```

More info:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/loadRemoteImage.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show the images inmediately you should use **network.download()** instead of display.loadRemoteImage()

In your example:

```
local params = {}
params.progress = true
for i=1,n do
    network.download(
        URLlimpia,
        "GET",
        networkListener,
        params,
        LOGO" .. i .. ".png",
        system.TemporaryDirectory
        )
end
```

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/download.html